# How to get data between two date range?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get the data from two different date range.How can i achive this?I have tried and got the data for starting date.

**Controller**

```php
public function detail(Request $request,$id)
{
    if($request->startdate) {
        $advance =Advancepayment::where('date',$request->startdate)->get();
    } else {
        $advance = Advancepayment::all();
    }

    return view('admin.managesalary.detail',compact('advance'));
}
```

**blade file**

```php
<form action="{{route('managesalary.detail',$user->id)}}" 
      method="GET" 
      class="form-horizontal"
>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Search</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- Date Picker -->
            <div class="input-group date " id="startDate">
                <strong>From</strong>
                <input 
                    type='date'
                    value="{{request()->startdate}}"
                    name="startdate"
                    class="form-control"
                />
            </div>
            <!-- Time Picker -->
            <div class="input-group date" id="startTime">
                <strong>To</strong>
                <input type='date'
                    value="{{request()->enddate}}"
                    name="enddate"
                    class="form-control"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="border-top">
        <div class="card-body">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
            <a href="{{route('managesalary.detail',$user->id)}}"
               class="btn btn-md btn-danger"
            >
                Clear
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**route**

```php
Route::get('managesalary/detail/{id}',[
    'as' => 'managesalary.detail',
    'uses' => 'ManagesalaryController@detail'
]);
```

Expected result as below:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's the date range is from last year 15/04 to this year 15/04, the code will be like

```
$from = date('2018-04-15');
$to = date('2019-04-15');

$advance = Advancepayment::whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->get();
```

if there is condition the $to is empty you can put a conditional

```
public function detail(Request $request,$id)
{
    $from = $request->input('startdate');
    $to = $request->input('enddate');
    if ( empty($to) && empty($from) ) {
        $advance = Advancepayment::all();
    } elseif ( empty($to) && ! empty($from) ) {
        $advance = Advancepayment::where('date', $from)->get();
        // or Advancepayment::where('date', '>', $from)->get(); depending upon your requirmeent
    } else {
        $advance = Advancepayment::whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the model scope

More about scopes

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes
- https://medium.com/@janaksan_/using-scope-with-laravel-7c80dd6a2c3d

Code:

```
    /**
     * Scope a query to only include the last n days records
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeWhereDateBetween($query,$fieldName,$fromDate,$todate)
    {
        return $query->whereDate($fieldName,'>=',$fromDate)->whereDate($fieldName,'<=',$todate);
    }
```

And in the controller, if you are using the Carbon library for handling dates, add the Carbon Library to top

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

**OR**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
```

To get the **last 10 days** record from now

```
 $lastTenDaysRecord = ModelName::whereDateBetween('created_at',(new Carbon)->subDays(10)->toDateString(),(new Carbon)->now()->toDateString() )->get();
```

To get the **last 30 days** record from now

```
 $lastThirtyDaysRecord = ModelName::whereDateBetween('created_at',(new Carbon)->subDays(30)->toDateString(),(new Carbon)->now()->toDateString() )->get();
```

So for your situation:

```
$recordResults = ModelName::whereDateBetween('filedName','2019-04-10','2019-04-12')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function detail(Request $request,$id)
{
$startdate=$request->input('from');
$enddate=$request->input('to');   
if(!empty($request->startdate) && !empty($enddate)) {
    $advance =Advancepayment::whereBetween('date',[$startdate,$enddate])->get();
} 
else if(!empty($request->startdate) && empty($enddate))
{
    $advance =Advancepayment::where('date','>=',$request->startdate)->get();

}
else
{
    $advance = Advancepayment::all();
}

return view('admin.managesalary.detail',compact('advance'));
}
```