# Comparing a database date field with date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

Compare database date with a date

I want to check the database date field is less than 5 days or not

I tried with Carbon class which output values in integer and MySQL database returns value in string or object

```php
$ticket = Tickets::select('created_at')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
```

I want to check if this result of date is less than 5 days or not
for i.e.  if the current result date is 01-05-2019 then message should be "ticket is older than 5 days"

Comment: What's column is date type to compare?

Comment: the type is timestamp

Comment: well actually i want to check the ticket date is older than 5 days or not

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question, you still want to get the Ticket whether it's older than 5 days or not? Can you show how you're wanting to displaying the message e.g. pass it to a blade file or return just that string from the controller?

Comment: yes return string from controller

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. This will return the date difference from today.

```
$ticket = Tickets::selectRaw('abs(datediff(created_at,"'.\Carbon\Carbon::now().'")) as day')->where('id','=',$id)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just change the current date to 5 days less and compare it

```
  $date = new DateTime;
  $date->modify('-5 days');
  $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $ticket = Tickets::where('created_at', $formatted_date)->where('id','=',$id)->first();
```

if you want to ignore the timestamp and compare date only you may need to do

```
 $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
 $ticket = Tickets::where(Date('created_at'), $formatted_date)->where('id','=',$id)->first();
```

I have not tested it, but it seems these code should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the model scope

More about scopes:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes
- https://medium.com/@janaksan_/using-scope-with-laravel-7c80dd6a2c3d

So add this scope method to your model that is `Ticket`

```
   /**
     * Scope a query to only include the last n days records
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeWhereDateOccurs($query, $fieldName, $upToDate,$noOfDays = 5)
    {
        $startFrom = \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parse($upToDate)->toDateTimeString();
        $endUpTo =  \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::createFromDate( $startFrom)->subDays( $noOfDays)->toDateTimeString();

        return $query->whereDate($fieldName, '>=', $startFrom)->whereDate($fieldName, '<=', $endUpTo);
    }
```

So now we are done with the method

Now in your controller

```
$ticket = Tickets::where('id','=',$id)
                  ->WhereDateOccurs( 'created_at', '01-05-2019',5)
                  ->get();
```

and here is the query log generated

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `tickets` 
WHERE  Date(`created_at`) >= ? 
       AND Date(`created_at`) <= ? 
       AND `id` = ? 
       AND `tickets`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

and I am using softdeletes so the  **deleted_at IS NULL** is added to all the query builder.

Comment: It looks like you have posted four answers (including this one) by copying and pasting. I normally flag as duplicates, but you appear to have tailored these a bit, so some of them will escape in terms of uniqueness. In general, please do not go looking for opportunity to re-paste your answers - it copies+pastes errors too, and the answers will start to diverge over time.

Comment: The questions are [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56037803), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55861536), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55585749), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55683607).